# How can I turn nested loop into idiomatic numpy code for creating tournaments results matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a two-dimensional array where columns are tournaments and rows are results of players. What I would like to do is to create results matrix where every row represents win frequency of a particular player against everyone else.

Here is my naive solution to this problem.

```
import numpy as np

input_example = np.array([
    [55.90, 81.50, 76.60, 69.50],
    [52.50, 74.60, 74.00, 64.80],
    [52.40, 74.90, 78.20, 60.90],
    [52.60, 78.90, 77.60, 60.80],
    ])

output_example = np.array([
    [0.50, 1.00, 0.75, 0.75],
    [0.00, 0.50, 0.50, 0.25],
    [0.25, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50],
    [0.25, 0.75, 0.50, 0.50],
    ])

def results_matrix(tournament_results):
    players, tournaments = tournament_results.shape
    res_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(players, tournaments))
    for n in range(players):
        for m in range(players):
            if n == m:
                res_matrix[n][m] = 0.50
                continue
            res_matrix[n][m] = (tournament_results[n] > tournament_results[m]).sum() / tournaments
    return res_matrix

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res_matrix = results_matrix(input_example)
    assert np.array_equal(res_matrix, output_example)
```

While it produces the correct results, I would like to turn this into idiomatic numpy solution so that it would work fast with large inputs.

You may assume that the results are distinct in a particular tournament so that no pair of players can have identical result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
players, tournaments = input_example.shape
arr0 = input_example.reshape(players, 1, tournaments)
arr1 = input_example.reshape(1, players, tournaments)
res_matrix = (arr0 > arr1).sum(2)/tournaments
res_matrix[np.arange(players), np.arange(players)] = 0.5
```

EDIT:
If you don't have enough memory to do it that way, there's no escaping loops. But you can simply use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to make your code run faster as it is now.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

input_example = np.array([
    [55.90, 81.50, 76.60, 69.50],
    [52.50, 74.60, 74.00, 64.80],
    [52.40, 74.90, 78.20, 60.90],
    [52.60, 78.90, 77.60, 60.80],
    ])

output_example = np.array([
    [0.50, 1.00, 0.75, 0.75],
    [0.00, 0.50, 0.50, 0.25],
    [0.25, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50],
    [0.25, 0.75, 0.50, 0.50],
    ])

def results_matrix(tournament_results):
    players, tournaments = tournament_results.shape
    res_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(players, players))
    for n in range(players):
        for m in range(players):
            if n == m:
                res_matrix[n][m] = 0.50
                continue
            res_matrix[n][m] = (tournament_results[n] > tournament_results[m]).sum() / tournaments
    return res_matrix

@jit(nopython=True)
def results_matrix_ba(tournament_results):
    players, tournaments = tournament_results.shape
    res_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(players, players))
    for n in range(players):
        for m in range(players):
            if n == m:
                res_matrix[n][m] = 0.50
                continue
            res_matrix[n][m] = (tournament_results[n] > tournament_results[m]).sum() / tournaments
    return res_matrix

print('running w/o numba')
%timeit assert np.array_equal(output_example, results_matrix(input_example))
print('running with numba')
%timeit assert np.array_equal(output_example, results_matrix_ba(input_example))
```

Output:

```
running w/o numba
The slowest run took 4.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 5: 71.9 µs per loop
running with numba
The slowest run took 5.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 7.74 µs per loop
```

Another example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
input_example = np.random.rand(900, 500)

print('running w/o numba')
%timeit results_matrix(input_example)
print('running with numba')
%timeit results_matrix_ba(input_example)
```

Output:

```
running w/o numba
1 loop, best of 5: 4.72 s per loop
running with numba
1 loop, best of 5: 407 ms per loop
```

Comment: When trying it on a larger input size 9000x5000 I got `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 377. GiB for an array with shape (9000, 9000, 5000) and data type bool`

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo I added another option i think might help in your case

Comment: great job, with numba it runs 4 times faster for an array of size 9000x5000. I'm wondering whether it is possible to add multiprocessing to achieve further speedup?

Comment: update: I used `@njit(parallel=True)` decorator with `prange` instead of `range` and it gave 7x speedup over `@jit(nopython=True)` decorator and 28x speedup over my initial solution for an array of size 9000x5000.

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo good job, ty for the update.